# How to deal with missing coefficients while bootstrapping regressions

Tags: multiple-regression, bootstrap, regression-coefficients

I'm using R boot() function to perform regression bootstrapping.

When boot() resamples my data, can happen that some coefficients are missing, especially in the case of factor variables with many cases.

How would you deal with such situation, from the theoretical point of view?

In my implementation I substitute the missing coefficients with NAs, therefore ignoring them when building statistics over the bootstrapped distribution.

As an alternative I thought of using 0, but wouldn't it work as a shrinkage regularization pushing the distribution towards 0?

In other occasions, the regression function crashes because some factors variable are stripped of all levels but one and there cannot be a predictor with just one value. In this case I totally ignore the coefficients on this regression and give back just NAs. But I can't understand if it is ok to loose a whole regression just for one predictor being useless. Should I strip the predictor?

In conclusion I'd like to know:
- How to deal with missing coefficients, should I use NAs or Zeros.
- How to deal with regression function crashes often due to predictors left with just one level? should I strip the predictor?

Thanks

Comment: If you're dropping variables, you've got some very sparse data. I'd be more concerned about that, I think I'd try to reduce the number of categories in the predictors.

Comment: actually the main problem is that the numerosity of the study is quite low. I can see that loosing categories can be a problem even with a good sample size if you have complex interaction. furthermore, as rare as it can be, with bootstrapping you have always a > 0 probability of a sample being very unbalanced and lose some or all of a predictor categories. So there should be a proper way to cope with it.

Answer (score 3):

One method that can be used (with caution!!) is a stratified bootstrap. That is, suppose we have 20 subjects in group 1 and 20 in group 2. Then we can resample our data, *conditional* on these sample sizes (i.e. we resample 20 from group 1 and 20 from group 2). Because of this, we are now insured that the estimator of the difference will be defined in each bootstrap sample.

In terms of the caution, you need to realize that you potentially could be performing bootstrapping on very small subsamples! A trivial example is suppose we stratified by x, but x was continuous. Then each sample would be it's own strata and our estimated variance would be 0. Clearly a problem.

In your case, I'm sure you have more than 1 observation per level, but you still need to be wary of the results if the number of observations per level is very small. If that's the case, I would certainly consider Jeremy's suggestion of trying to combine levels that may be very similar to each other in nature.